# Extract model from device name

Tags: c#, regex

`Mozilla/2.0 (Linux; Android 2.0; KK; SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit`

Need `SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T` to be extracted.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit`

Need `SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T` to be extracted.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; XT1032 Build/LPBS23.13-56-2; wv) AppleWebKit`

Need `XT1032 Build/LPBS23.13-56-2` to be extracted.

The logic is:

```
1. Take first [(.....)]
2. Take text after last semicolon [;]
3. Or take text after last semicolon [;] and before [; wv]
```

What I have for now:

`.*?\(.*;(?<model>.*?)(; wv)?\)`

But this works for first 2 examples and for the third example it returns `wv`.

Comment: Do you want to use Regex only? OR other logic is good to use ?

Comment: I have a feeling that it's easier to be done without regex (given that you might have "()" inside model name).

Comment: @Evk, yes thats the case unfortuantely. `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; MotoE2(4G-LTE) Build/LXI22.50-53.8; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/45.0.2454.95 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Comment: You probably can do this with .NET-specific feature of balancing groups in regex, but I just don't see why bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.*)\(.*;(?<model>(?!( wv))[^;()]*(\(.??\))?[^;)]*)+?(;.*)?\).*$
```

matches

- *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; **XT1032 Build/LPBS23.13-56-2**; wv)* AppleWebKit
- *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; **SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T**) AppleWebKit*
- *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; **SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T**) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36*
- *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; **Moto G (4) Build/MPJ24.139-23.1**) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36*

The negative lookAhead (`(?! wv)`) made it for me.

I guess you can still make the expression more slim, but this one should fit at first(used with /gi-Flags[global, case insensitive).

Important things that make it work:

- negative lookahead (?!...)
- lazy quantifier ?? (the second '?' makes
  it lazy, not greedy)

EDIT: added the condition that no ')' may be included in the matching group
EDIT2: modified expression so it fits even more strings

Comment: Can you check why it doesn't work for this `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I modified it so it matches your longer version as well. However, it doesnt match your device name anymore if it contains a ')' (if that exists)

Comment: Better now! Thanks. I also noticed that there may be subbaraces like this one: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Moto G (4) Build/MPJ24.139-23.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36`. It extracts `Moto G (4`. I guess that will be hard to consider?

Comment: If you want this as well, I'm afraid you'd need to use recursive regex.
You can see a question with this [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), but I can't edit my answer right now with this feature, I'd need to do it in the evening(I'm at work). You'd need to allow '(' and ')' as long as the count of them is equal.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I modified it and now it captures all your examples, even without recursive regex. But take care, it only matches one pair of bracers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
;\s*(?<model>([^;)])*)
```

I just tried it and the second match will return the desired string in the named group. This will not match the

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux
```

part, though, but it doesn't seem like you need that part.

Comment: Works, but the problem is that it is a problem to find out which match do I need as it returns multiple matches. but thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it always be the same match, since the only thing that changes is the wv? :)

Comment: Not unfortunately, because this is just an example and there are many more other formats. For example `Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/16.0.2168/88.150; U; es) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16`. The problem is that this matching is done in CLR function for SQL Server `[dbo].[DeviceExtractor] (@input NVARCHAR(MAX), @pattern NVARCHAR(MAX))` and I need it to be the same for all type of patterns. Don't want to hardcode index of matches as it will be different for different patterns.

Comment: If you don't know which item in the parantheses-enclosed list is the device name you have a problem. Because that'd require you to be able to detect device names (I think that's what you're looking for) :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply split on the semicolon to an array:

```
string[] parts = myUserAgent.Split(";");
```

and now you can get "SAMSUNG ...." by:

```
string temp = parts[3];
```

in the end use the "replace" function to remove unintentional characters.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to split the string. The question is about regex solution.